# Could a group of several men and one woman be called "a group of men and women"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

If not, what's the correct way of referring to the group?

Comment: .A mixed group.

Comment: 'A group comprising one woman and several men' or ' a group consisting of one woman and several men'

Comment: _A group of people_ would be the completely neutral way of putting it.  It depends on what you want to emphasise.  If you say _a mixed group_ (as suggested above) then it emphasises the fact there are people there of both genders.  If that's not something you particularly need to highlight, then the emphasis might be confusing, in which case _a group of people_ sidesteps the whole issue.

Comment: if he "doesn't need to highlight it" he wouldn't ask the question.  of course, naturally, if you "leave off the men and women part!" it's a non-issue.

Comment: Agreed with @EdwinAshworth, a real world example is Olympics sports : (http://www.olympic.org/multimedia-player/all-photos/2014/08/23/-gold-medalist-of-the-mixed-international-team-of-table-tennis-/)

Comment: If it is a group to which both men and women are invited, and normally both sexes attend, then the fact that only one woman or no women show up for this particular meeting, does not mean that it ceases to be,  in a certain sense, a *mixed group*; or *group of men and women*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Group" is not the only collective noun you can use in this case, although it's certainly accurate. If the individuals are close to each other but separated from others, **cluster** can be used. In informal speech, **bunch** is often used, as in "There's a bunch of reporters outside". If the group is large, it can be a **crowd**, and the size which determines large enough can be wildly variable.

In all cases, the use of "women" when there is only one woman in the group depends entirely on your intent. It is used when the intent is to establish the presence of both sexes in the group. To use something like "a group of men and one woman" is to draw attention to the fact that there is only one woman in the group.

Comment: of course, you could say "group" or "bunch" or whatever .. but, so what, WRR?  the OP is getting at the concept that the phrase "men and women" is, let's us say, "a bit silly" in that situation (although literally correct). there are plenty of examples of this.  and the answer is you just have to spell it out, there's no sort of common phrase, right.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Sorry for the first version - messed up the edit and produced two versions.

Comment: no need to be sorry to me, old bean!  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of "unusual cases" like that where, quite simply, there's no general, common way to express the idea.  You just have to spell it out.

Yes, if you had 1000 women and one man, it would indeed be .. incongruous, silly .. to describe it as a "group of men and women".

Quite simply, it is spelled-out .. so, "and we found a group of about 1000 people, almost all men with one or two women."

It's not complicated and it's "just that simple."

Sure, there are cases where you have to spell out unusual, incongruous sets.

---

User, I think the usual "newsreader language" to fastly describe such a group would be "a group, **predominantly** composed of men...".  You can see Brian Williams rattling that off.

Answer (score 1):

So long it has element- even one - I might call it group of men women.